# inverse cumulative probability of beta distribution in php

Tags: php, beta-distribution

I am trying to find a function with the functionality equivalent to [inverse beta CDF](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/AbstractRealDistribution.html#inverseCumulativeProbability%28double%29).

I searched for the function but i could not find anything which can do this task.
Is there any library function which can do this? Or is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You mean the PHP equivalent of MS Excel's BETAINV function?

Comment: you have the (source code)[http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/AbstractRealDistribution.html#line.128] just translate it to PHP :)

Comment: Then take a look at the implementation in [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) which is in the [Calculation/Statistics](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation/Statistical.php) file... you might need to tweak it slightly to remove the other functions and PHPExcel-specific elements in the code